# Iterating a group of folders and files while removing certain files that are contained in a list

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of files that I download that contain files that I want to remove. I would like to create a list of some form, the script should support blobbing so I can be pretty aggressive with file removal without getting into the complexities of using regex within the list of files.

I am also stumped in that I put a sleep command within the loop of my script, and that is not getting run after each iteration, but only once at the end of run.

Here is the script

```
# Get to the place where all the durty work happens
cd /Volumes/Videos

FILES=".DS_Store
*.txt
*.sample
*.sample.*
*.samples"


if [ "$(pwd)" == "/Volumes/Videos" ]; then
    echo "You are currently in $(pwd)"
    echo "You would not have read the above if this script were operating anywhere else"

    # Dekete fikes from list above
    for f in "$FILES"
    do
        echo "Removing $f";
        rm -f "$f";
        echo "$f has been deleted";
        sleep 10;
        echo "";
        echo "";
    done

    # See if dir is empty, ask if we want to delete it or keep it
    # Iterate evert movie file, see if we want to nuke contents.  Maybe use part of last openned to help find those files fast
else
    # Not in the correct directory
    echo "This script is trying to alter files in a location that it should not be working"
    echo "Script is currently trying to work in $(pwd)"
    exit 1
fi
```

The main thing that has be completely stumped is the `sleep` command.  It is run once, not once per file iteration.  If I have 100 files to go through I get 10 seconds of sleep, not 100*10.

I will be adding in some other features, like if a file is smaller than x bytes, go ahead and delete it too. These files will have spaces and other odd characters in the filenames, am I creating my variables correctly to make this script handle those scenarios as well as be as POSIX compliant as possible.  I will change the shebang to sh over bash and try to add in set -o noun set and set -o err exit though I tend to have a lot of trouble when I do that.

Is there a better form of list I should be using?  I am not objectionable to storing the pattern match list in a separate file.  I can include it, or read it in with any of a few commands.

These are also nested files, a dir, that contains files, or a dir that contains a dir that contains some files.  Something like this:

```
 /Volumes/Videos:
 The Great guy in a tree
  The Great guy in a tree S01e01
    sample.avi
    readme.txt
    The Great guy in a tree S01e01.mpg    
  The Great guy in a tree S01e02 
    The Great guy in a tree S01e02.mpg    
  The Great guy in a tree S01e03 
    The Great guy in a tree S01e03.mpg    
  The Great guy in a tree S01e04 
    The Great guy in a tree S01e04.mpg
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your script is not working as you expect is because your `for` loop is written incorrectly. This example shows what is going on:

```
$ i=0
$ FILES=".DS_Store
*.txt
*.sample
*.sample.*
*.samples"
$ for f in "$FILES"; do echo $((++i)) "$f"; done
1 .DS_Store
*.txt
*.sample
*.sample.*
*.samples
```

Note that only one number is output, indicating that the loop is only going around once. Also, no pathname expansion has occurred.

In order to make your script work as you expect, you can remove the quotes around `"$FILES"`. This means that each word in your string will be evaluated separately, rather than all at once. It also means that pathname expansion of the wildcards that you are using will occur, so all files ending in `.txt` will be removed, which I guess is what you meant.

Instead of using a string to store your list of expressions, you might prefer to make use of an array:

```
FILES=( '.DS_Store' '*.txt' '*.sample' '*.sample.*' '*.samples' )
```

The quotes around each element prevent expansion (so the array only has 5 elements, not the fully expanded list). You could then change your loop to `for f in ${FILES[@]}` (again, no double quotes results in each element of the list being expanded).

Although removing the quotes fixes your script, I would agree with @hek2mgl's suggestion of using `find`. It allows you to find files by name, size, date modified and a lot more in one line. If you want to pause between the deletion of each file, you could use something like this:

```
find \( -name "*.sample" -o -name "*.txt" \) -delete -exec sleep 10 \;
```

Comment: I tried that, adding in a , to show the current place a want to search find . \(-iname "*.sample" -o -iname "*.txt"\)
find: -o: no expression before -o and deleted the rest so it just finds, I get:find: -o: no expression before -o

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Maybe it would be better if you edited your question to show exactly what you've tried and the new error that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`:

```
find -type f -name '.DS_Store' -o -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.sample.*' -o -name '*.samples' -delete
```

Comment: Is this a Linux only command or posix compliant ? On Mac OS X /*BSD you have to define your search path as the criteria after the `find` command. `find /path/to/search  -iname "*searcheord*" ` after that I get lost on hoe to do multiple OR operators in a row.

Comment: @Scott If you omit the search path, it uses the current directory as default. Don't have a BSD by the hand. Can test the whole command later

Comment: Some are suggesting I open a new thread thst is more clear, perhaps I should try that.